# How does the data get stored in the 'singer' table when didn't make a commit for the object of that class?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, many-to-many, associations

There are certain things I do not understand about a small hibernate application for which the `mapping xml` is shown below.

```
    <class name="pojo.Ghazal" table="ghazal">
        <id name="s_no">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="poem" />
        <property name="poet" />
        <map name="map" table="linked" cascade="all">
            <key column="s_no" />
            <index column="key_" type="string" />
            <many-to-many column="val_" class="pojo.Singer" />
        </map>
    </class>

    <class name="pojo.Singer" table="singer">
        <id name="s_no">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="singer_name" />
        <property name="country" />
    </class>
```

There are 2 `pojos` namely `Ghazal` and `Singer`. I understand the mapping of `Singer` class, but I do not understand that of the `Ghazal` class.

When I run the following program :

```
    Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
    SessionFactory sessFact = config.buildSessionFactory();
    Session sess = sessFact.openSession();
    Transaction trans = sess.beginTransaction();
    Ghazal ghazal = new Ghazal();

    Singer singer = new Singer();
    singer.setCountry("Pakistan");
    singer.setSinger_name("Mehdi Hasan");
    Singer singer_1 = new Singer();
    singer_1.setCountry("India");
    singer_1.setSinger_name("Jagjit Singh");

    HashMap map = new HashMap();
    map.put("key_1", singer);
    map.put("key_2", singer_1);

    ghazal.setPoem("Woh Jo Hum Mein Tum Mein Qarar Tha");
    ghazal.setPoet("Momin Khan Momin");
    ghazal.setMap(map);

    sess.save(ghazal);
    trans.commit();
```

the data gets automatically stored in the three tables namely `ghazal, linked, singer`. 
How does the data get stored in the `singer` table while I committed only the object of `ghazal` class ?

*And what does the tag :*

```
<many-to-many...>
```

*do* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When instance of `Ghazal` is persisted via

```
sess.save(ghazal);
```

operation is cascaded to the instances of Singer that are in map referenced from `Ghazal`. Save (among other operations) is cascaded because attribute cascade is set to `all`.

```
<map name="map" table="linked" cascade="all">
    <key column="s_no" />
    <index column="key_" type="string" />
    <many-to-many column="val_" class="pojo.Singer" />
</map>
```

In this case many-to-many means that single instance of `Singer` can be in relation to many instances of `Ghazal` and single instance of `Ghazal` can be in relation to many instances of `Singer`. Collection mappings are documented for example in [Hibernate reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html).

Comment: _"..operation is cascaded to the instances of Singer that are in map referenced from Ghazal. Save (among other operations) is cascaded because attribute cascade is set to all.."_ can you please make it more clear ? I just didn't understand **'how'** is this happening ? Please explain the `cascade` attribute and what does actually the attribute `class` inside the `many-to-many` tag do ?